# How do I make standard actions (like TEditCopy) recognize additional controls (like TEmbeddedWB)?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, action, c++builder, twebbrowser

I am generally satisified with functionality of  `TEditCut`, `TEditCopy`, `TEditPaste` and `TEditSelectAll` except they don't work on any controls which are not standard.

For example, they may work fine on `TEdit` or `TMemo` controls, but not on `TEmbeddedWB` — with it, standard actions are always disabled regardless of whether text is selected, even though `TEmbeddedWB` has methods like `CopyToClipboard` and `SelectAll`.

How can I make standard actions work with `TEmbeddedWB`? How do standard actions determine whether they should be enabled or disabled (and in what event they do it — is it in the `OnUpdate` event)? Can I extend standard actions to add support for unrecognized components, or do I need to write their replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default Edit actions do not work on a `TEmbeddedWB` control, because that component does not descend from `TCustomEdit`. `TEditAction`, which `TEditSelectAll` descends from, only knows how to handle `TCustomEdits`.

Use the `OnUpdate` and `OnExecute` events of the action to override this behaviour. Note that the default behaviour then will be ignored, so implement that manually. Here an example for a `TEditSelectAll` action.

```
procedure TForm1.EditSelectAll1Update(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EditSelectAll1.Enabled := (Screen.ActiveControl is TEmbeddedWB) or
    EditSelectAll1.HandlesTarget(ActiveControl)
end;

procedure TForm1.EditSelectAll1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ActiveControl is TEmbeddedWB then
    TEmbeddedWB(Screen.ActiveControl).SelectAll
  else
    EditSelectAll1.ExecuteTarget(Screen.ActiveControl);
end;
```

Or use the same events of the ActionList (or `OnActionUpdate` and `OnActionExecute` of an ApplicationEvents component) to centralize this custom behaviour:

```
procedure TForm1.ActionList1Update(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Action is TEditAction then
  begin
    TCustomAction(Action).Enabled := (Screen.ActiveControl is TEmbeddedWB) or
      Action.HandlesTarget(Screen.ActiveControl);
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ActionList1Execute(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Action is TEditSelectAll) and (Screen.ActiveControl is TEmbeddedWB) then
  begin
    TEmbeddedWB(Screen.ActiveControl).SelectAll;
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks just like what I needed to handle this.